# How to publish to Kafka from Spark using Structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing a Spark application that reads messages from a Kafka topic, looks up records in a DB, constructs new messages and publishes them to another Kafka topic. Here's what my code looks like -

```
val inputMessagesDataSet: DataSet[InputMessage] = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1")
  .option("subscribe", "input-kafka-topic1")
  .load()
  .select($"value")
  .mapPartitions{r =>
     val messages: Iterator[InputMessage] = parseMessages(r)
  }

inputMessagesDataSet
  .writeStream
  .foreachBatch(processMessages _)
  .trigger(trigger)
  .start
  .awaitTermination

def processMessages(inputMessageDataSet: Dataset[InputMessage]) = {
   // fetch stuff from DB and build a DataSet[OutputMessage]
   val outputMessagesDataSet: DataSet[OutputMessage] = ...
   // now queue to another kafka topic
  outputMessagesDataSet
      .writeStream
      .trigger(trigger)
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1")
      .option("topic", "output-kafka-topic")
      .option("checkpointLocation", loc)
      .start
      .awaitTermination
}
```

But I get an error saying

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;`
on line
`outputMessagesDataSet.writeStream`

This seems to be because `outputMessagesDataSet` is not created using `readStream`.
The reason I'm not constructing the `DataSet[OutputMessage]` in the original `mapPartitions()` is because the classes that are needed for fetching DB records, etc. are not serializable, so it throws `NotSerializableException`.

How do I construct a new DataSet and queue to Kafka?

Comment: why are you using foreachBatch?

Comment: @AlexOtt is there an alternative?

Comment: just use `writeStream`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka

Comment: @AlexOtt ahh that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreachBatch` accepts a static DataSet, so you need to use `write`, not `writeStream`

Alternatively, you can `writeStream.format("kafka")` without using the `forEachBatch`